# Problem saving uploaded files in Python3

Tags: file-upload, python-3.x

i control the problem of the data what is uploaded by the POST method, in the web.
 If the file is a text theres no problem but the trouble comes when it's an encoded file, as a Picture or other. What the when the system insert the data into the file.
Well it doesn 't encoded in the right way. I will put all the code, from the area whats take the environ['wsgi.input'] to the area thats save the file:

```
# Here the data from the environ['wsgi.input'], 
# first i convert the byte into a string delete the first 
# field that represent the b and after i strip the single quotes
tmpData = str(rawData)[1:].strip("' '")
dat = tmpData.split('\\r')#Then i split all the data in the '\\r'
s = open('/home/hidura/test.png', 'w')#I open the test.png file.
for cont in range(5,150):#Now beging in the 5th position to the 150th position
s.write(dat[cont])#Insert the piece of the data in the file.
s.close()#Then closed.
```

Where is the mistake?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you convert the binary data to a string? A png file *is* binary data. Just write the binary data to the file. You need to open the file in binary mode as well.

```
s = open('/home/hidura/test.png', 'wb')
s.write(data)
```